# jquery autocomplete javascript, php and mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to get Jquery auto-complete working like http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

so i downloaded the references and included them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

with this short code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#auto').autocomplete(
        {
            source: "./file.php",
            minLength: 3
        })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
   .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
   .append( item.auto )
   .appendTo( ul );
};  
})
</script>
```

but i keep getting this error: **autocomplete is not a function**

i do not know exactly where is my wrong !

Comment: Double check your src attributes

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you meant by double check.

Comment: Is jquery loaded from the specified link in src ?

Comment: jquery is downloaded, because $() is found. jQuery UI is not however

Comment: where can i find it ? i downloaded libraries from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and assumed i had all what i need.

Comment: Are you sure, that you include the script of autocomplete module? Cause jquery ui can be provided as a bunch of files.

Comment: You're using a custom version of jQuery UI. Maybe you didn't include autocomplete? Try the full package for testing.

Comment: do you have guys a link of a full autocomplete libraries ?

Comment: i have dounloaded this one assuming it's full package http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jquery-ui.js

I was had same problem. i added jquery-ui.js and That error gone.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```